# How to print table as landscape using pagedown and kableextra r packages?

Tags: r, kableextra, pagedown

I'm using r package pagedown and kableextra to print a long table in landscape format. But I'm not getting how to do it.

Comment: did you already try the `landscape()` example at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/kableExtra.pdf?

Comment: Yes, it is useful only when output is pdf file. I'm using pagedown package and output is in the Mozilla browser.

Comment: have you tried changing the `paperwidth` and `paperheight` parameters in the YAML header?

Comment: @RaoulDuke, No.